# Сетка Bootstrap для мобильных телефонов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Есть 3 `<div>`:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">блок 1</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">блок 2</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">блок 3</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы, когда ширина экрана становилась `xs`, то блок 3 выезжал наверх, то есть получалось так:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">блок 3</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">блок 1</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">блок 2</div>
```

Comment: на бутстрап не знаю а вот на flexbox  легко..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Пример

```css
[class*=col-] {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-push-8 col-sm-push-8">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-pull-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-pull-4">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```